# Select current row in gridview with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a **gridview** with 3 columns and multiple rows. The 1st column contains names, the second column contains a dropdownlist with two items "yes" and "no". So, when I want to set a row to "yes" the 3rd column should populate a textbox, just only for the row where we selected "yes".

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in GridViewP.Rows)
{                
            DropDownList ddlSelection = new DropDownList();
            ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("Yes"));
            ddlSelection.Items.Add(new ListItem("No"));

            ddlSelection.TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.ddlSelection_SelectedIndexChanged);
            ddlSelection.AutoPostBack = true;

            r.Cells[1].Controls.Add(ddlSelection);             
 }   


protected void ddlSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        DropDownList changed = (DropDownList)sender;            

        if (changed.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {    
            foreach (GridViewRow r in GridViewP.Rows)
            {
                TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
                r.Cells[2].Controls.Add(txtbox);
            }    
        }
}
```

How can I populate the 3th column with the textbox on `selecteditem` = "yes"? The way it works like now is that when I set dropdownlist on "yes" the textbox is showing up for each row.

Comment: Why don't you use  [`GridView.SelectRow(rowIndex)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectrow(v=vs.100).ASPX)? Then you can use `GridView.SelectedRow.FindControl("TextBoxID")` to find the `TextBox` and make it visible and set the text accordingly.

Comment: im adding the textbox control on runtime, so i think its not possible to find the control with Findcontrol? Could you be more specific? Its the first time for me working with C#. thanks anyway

Comment: Why do you add it programmatically at all? You just have to make it visible.

Comment: yes youre right, thats easier. I did it thath way, but still have the same problem when selecting "yes". it  makes the textbox.findcontrol invisible then its dissapears on all rows.

Comment: well i fixed it with:

 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)changed.NamingContainer;   instead of the foreach loop.